# Parse "parse new" doesn't create configuration folder as expected

Tags: parse-platform

I am following this tutorial to use parse.com hosting,

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#hosting/windows

It says a config folder with json file will be created with "parse new", but it doesn't, I only get the public and cloud folders. Not sure what's going wrong here. Anyone know where I can find a copy of the file and put into my folder, so I can configure it's public URL?

Answer (score 0):

The guide says :

`The config directory contains a JSON configuration file that you shouldn't normally need to deal with`

And then afterwards says

`In the 'Hosting' section of your app's settings, you'll see a field at the top that allows you to set your subdomain, e.g. your-custom-domain.parseapp.com.`

Perhaps that is what you are looking for?